# OutputDebugString - Not showing in Output Window

Tags: c++, directx

This should output to the output window. However, it doesn't, and I'm not sure why. When I run it in debug mode, buffer = "*** NUM ADAPTERS = 2", but it doens't display in the output window.

```
UINT i = 0;
std::vector<IDXGIAdapter*> vAdapters;
while(dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &dxgiAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    vAdapters.push_back(dxgiAdapter);
    ++i;
}

char buffer[50];

sprintf_s(buffer, "***NUM ADAPTERS = %d", vAdapters.size());

OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
```

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Are you debugging (F5) or running it (ctrl+F5)? If the latter, that's your problem -- you need to just use F5.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Then where will it be displayed?

Comment: In the VS output window. e.g., http://i1212.photobucket.com/albums/cc452/jcoffin01/debug_zpsf213d96a.png

Answer (score 3):

When you start the program with debugger, OutputDebugString stuff appears in the output pane (you may have to switch to it and even select the output of program from the combo).

Outside you can use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to collect that output, certainly that way you will have to filter the messages by PID.

Comment: to be safe, start the DbgView in Admin mode

Comment: Is it normal that output appears either in Visual Studio output window or in DebugView, but not in both?